# Differences between Mario Bros for the NES and 25th Anniversary Super Mario Bros?

Tags: nintendo-wii, version-differences, mario-series, super-mario-bros

As part of the 25th anniversary celebrations, Nintendo has released [a couple of Wii bundles](http://gamesites.nintendo.com.au/mario-25th-anniversary-bundles/en_AU/index.php) that include some sort of variant of Mario Bros:

> 25th Anniversary SUPER MARIO BROS is pre-installed, the design is partially rearranged from the original SUPER MARIO BROS for NES

Does anyone know what the difference is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the screenshot shown on that page, it appears that the coin blocks have been relabeled with "25". I hope, at least, that this was the only "partially rearranged" issue in the 25th anniversary of a classic.

[image: super mario bros 25th anniversary screenshot]

Comment: +1 a friend sent me a dump of the 25th anniversary version. A binary diff against the original SMB showed that the only difference was the coin block tile.